# FlashDevelop - Haxe Trying to debug with Android and Flash

Tags: android, flash, haxe, flashdevelop, haxepunk

So I'm kind of new to Haxe I installed the setup and all the Android stuff (SDK,NDK,..) and it all ran fine with HTML5, Windows, and neko. However when I run with android I get "Error: Could not detect Android API platforms in "android/platforms". But I have couple of APIs in there so I don't understand what's going on. Here is a screenshot of my platforms folder (I used SDK Manager)

[image]

Do I need my Android device to be plugged in? If so how would FlashDevelop detect it.

Also, when I try and compile to flash I get an error:

[image]

Is there anything else I have to install to compile flash with Haxe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing flashplayer or you have not associated it with swf files. Goto https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html and dowload the appropiate flash debugger based on your system.
Then associate .swf filetypes with it.

You can also use FlashDevelop's appman tool which does this in a very simple and automated way. Open it on FD menu, tools, install software and find the players at "runtimes" list.

Comment: Thank you! this worked :D I've been also trying to build my project to windows/neko but this came up once I hovered my mouse over the window: Invalid field access
Called from com.haxepunk.utils.Input::onTouchMove line 577
Called from openfl._legacy.events.EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent line 98
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__dispatchEvent line 182
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__fireEvent line 244
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__onTouch line 1048
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__doProcessStageEvent line 465

Comment: Glad it worked. If you have another thing to ask,not related with this one,  please create a new question. Also if my answer was correct, please select it as best answer =)